# Force gcc to use more complex instructions

Tags: assembly, decompilation, gcc

I am reverse engineering a piece of assembly. I am trying to write the equivalent code in C, however, when I compile my code, gcc prefers to use simple instructions instead of the complex ones that are used in my assembly. I was wondering if I can suggest or force gcc to use more complex instructions.

**EDIT:** I have already tried using the `-O` options but they will change lots of other variables and therefore, don't look like a good solution.

You can find examples here:

```
// original assembly
lea     rdx, [rax+0x20]

// generated by gcc
add     rax, 0x20
mov     rdx, rax

// C code
0x20+((uint8_t *)lParm1)  // long lParm1
```

```
// original assembly
test    eax, eax

// generated by gcc
mov     [rbp-0x10], eax
cmp     [rbp-0x10], 0x0

// C code
if (!iVar)  // int iVar
```

```
// original assembly
mov     eax, [rax+0x40]

// generated by gcc
add     rax, 0x40
mov     eax, [rax]

// C code
(float)*(int *)(lParm1 + 0x40)
```

Comment: can you please share the c code that generates that set of instructions?

Comment: Often the original code smaller (is only one command vs. two). Therefore you may try to enable optimization for code size via `-Os` parameter.

Comment: I have already tried that. The thing is that it more or less achieves what I want but then changes lots of other variables. Therefore, doesn't seem like a good option

Comment: Please edit your question and include in detail what you already tried and why it  is not a suitable solution.

Comment: Actually in order to achieve what you want, you need to have a toolchain (including not just compiler frontend and backend, but also assembler and linker - linker if you use LTO or similar) which can produce the desired code. And then, depending on those (and the specs file - try `gcc -dumpspecs`) you can use `-mtune`, `-mcpu` and `-march` as well as some more architecture-specific options to optimize for a CPU model and so on. However, your question should be clarified further ... also, you may want to look at RetDec and LLVM IR, perhaps?!